# Program which behaves differently in/out of a debugger

Tags: code-golf

The challenge is to write a deterministic program (any language/OS) which takes no arguments or other input and **behaves differently in a debugger from how it behaves when not being debugged**.

For example, the program may output something when being debugged but not output anything when not being debugged. Or output something different in each case. Or it may crash when being debugged but not crash when not being debugged. Or vice-versa.

Caveats and clarifications:

- Timing differences do not count.
- Interpreted languages are permitted.
- To emphasize determinism: the behaviour must be exactly reproducible both in and out of debugging context.
- The presence of the debugger itself should the only difference between the two cases.

  - Telling the debugger to add inputs (stdin or argv ENV or whatever) is cheating, the debugger should run the program "as-is".
  - Changing the environment (e.g. running in a virtual machine or different OS, or changing OS settings such as memory limits) between debug and non-debug runs is not permitted.

Shortest code wins. I may award a bounty which reveals something interesting about how debuggers work.

Comment: Some debuggers output different text on startup to the normal compiler, thus any program seems to meet these conditions.  Does that count?

Comment: If it's the debugger producing the output and not the program itself then no.

Comment: Doesn't all output come from the debugger?  It's not clear to me what debugger output is vs. program output if we are making a distinction.

Comment: Define debugger?

Comment: What do you mean by debugger? Which one?

Comment: How do you define a debugger? If a language interpreter supports a "debug" mode (which, say, introduces nonstandard commands), does that count?

Comment: This reminds me the one time when I spent hours trying to figure out why a C++ program was finishing nearly instantly when not debugget, yet took several minutes to do its work while under a debugger. Turns out that when it was debugged, the default memory allocator took some extra care when allocating/freeing memory, and that particular program was creating an array of thousands of elements (each allocated with an individual `new()` call) which in the end added up.

Comment: Question is on hold because it's unclear what is being asked? Really? The first sentence outlines the requirements in black and white, no? Perhaps those putting the question on hold can clarify why they find it ambiguous rather than a link to a generic "it's unclear" message?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this challenge. Yes I see there are open questions but in my opinion it's very clear what is being asked. The parts that are perhaps unclear are specific points of validity/invalidity. I personally have a bit of a disclaimer in [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185519/51785) since it only detects if the program is running in debug mode and not whether a debugger is actually debugging it. I'm fully aware that I may need to delete this answer if it turns out that's not okay but it seems to have been received alright by the voting community so far.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## x86 and x64_64 machine language on Linux and OSX, 1 byte

```
0x0:  CC    int3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTPP1sjAxPr//3/JaTmJ6cX/datSK1KTi0sSk7MB)

`int 3` throws a `SIGTRAP` which will cause a debugger to stop as if it encountered a breakpoint. Outside of a debugger, the kernel terminates the process (thanks to @Ruslan for the correction).

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (x86 Linux and OSX), <s>14 11</s> 9 bytes

```c
main=204;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTPP1sjAxPr//3/JaTmJ6cX/datSK1KTi0sSk7MB)

The integer `204` corresponds to the `int 3` instruction; the TIO link is the same as above.

Comment: clear assignment in the C code, haven't seen that before.

Comment: Actually `SIGTRAP` doesn't result in `SIGABRT`, so the part about calling `abort()` is wrong. There's simply no default signal handler for `SIGTRAP`, so the kernel terminates the process (and the parent can use `WIFSIGNALED` to detect this and `WTERMSIG` to determine which signal happened).

Answer (score 10):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 0 bytes

In Dyalog APL, debugger vs no debugger is choosen by running one's workspace in either the IDE interpreter or the runtime interpreter.

Loading a completely empty default settings workspace into the IDE interpreter, immediately drops the user into REPL mode as applications must actively shut down the interpreter for it to quit:

[image: IDE REPL]

However, the runtime interpreter does not have a REPL mode, and so if an application comes to an end (for example because it is completely empty) and does not explicitly shut down the interpreter, it implicitly has attempted to reach REPL mode ("the APL session"), and complains:

[image: Runtime dialog]

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript on Firefox, 69 bytes

**WARNING**: This script may hang your browser! Do NOT test it with other browsers (e.g. Chrome) as it may crash your tab / browser.

```js
for(console.log(a={},i=99);--i;a=a.a={k:new Int8Array(1e9)});alert(1)
```

How: When debugger is enabled with `console` tab activated. `console.log` makes memory leak possible, and the program will run out of memory soon. When debugger is disabled, GC would clear memory allocated, and you would see an alert with text `1` finally.

Answer (score 8):

### MSVC (64-bit), <s>50</s> 35 bytes

```
main(){return IsDebuggerPresent();}
```

Exits with code 0 normally but 1 under the debugger (note that WinDbg does not automatically display the exit code but you can fake it by examining the stack). Edit: Saved 15 bytes thanks to @Ruslan.

Comment: Does MSVC require prototypes? You might then want to try with MinGW in C89 mode, to save some bytes.

Comment: @Ruslan Bah, shows how long it's been since I've used C...

Answer (score 7):

## T-SQL, 6 bytes

```
sp_who
```

Always returns an extra row under the executing user's name when the debugger is active.

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 29 bytes

```
import sys
sys.modules['pdb']
```

Without debugger (`python3 /tmp/foo.py`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/foo.py", line 2, in <module>
    sys.modules['pdb']
KeyError: 'pdb'
```

With debugger (`python3 -m pdb /tmp/foo.py`):

```
(empty output)
```

because `pdb` is loaded into an app-visible module in the second case.

Answer (score 4):

## Java, <s>131 102</s> 100 bytes

```java
v->(java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments()+"").split(":jdwp")
```

When running without a debugger this function returns an array of length 1. When running with a debugger, this returns an array of length 2 (greater than 1).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZBBS8QwEIXv/RWhp4TtBrzu2gVFFjzsxQURRGTaxphuOgnJpFJk/7o1XVZvj5k3w/deDyOsnVfYd6e5tRAjO4BB9l0wFgnItKzPFpnIWPmRsCXjUO6v4vbZma46UjCoX992DFg9j@sdv5xYQC0HQNBqUEjy8C/30JILk9SKnhKSGdTh5V4BcrGMHtEnugs6LdbIxaoshYzeGuLlpu@@fCnmbeFTYzPclXHMHGzI4PwPBoKOYklxnCKpQbpE0ucVWeTlg2qS1ipsWMlWjIME7@3EMVkrpFWo6ZPt2I0Q2@JcnOcf55e0cV7nAPmDaS4cNQXA6F2guqP36NqToiqqMKpQT1VMMdfa1fgL)

This technically detects if you *could* attach a debugger; not if one is currently connected... Not sure if that's valid

-23 bytes thanks to [Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236/olivier-gr%C3%A9goire) for mentioning that I can cut down on what I search for in the runtime parameters and for lambda-izing my answer

-5 bytes thanks to [Benjamin Urquhart](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84303/benjamin-urquhart) for noting that calling `toString` is dumb when I can let Java implicitly convert

-2 bytes thanks to [Benjamin Urquhart](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84303/benjamin-urquhart) for changing the return type

Comment: You can shorten it using a lambda. Also, it's very likely that you can test only on `:jdwp`, instead of `-agentlib:jdwp`. The `:` is to distinguish `runjdwp` from `-agentlib:jdwp`. [108 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY9BS8QwEIXv/RVDTwm6Yc@7WlBkYQ9lwQURxMNsmw2p6SQ0k2qR/e011cXbx5v34JsOR1z5oKlrP@bGYYxQoyX4LgAiI9sGulxRia1T50QNW09qd4W7F2/b2z2xNnqoAOF@HlfV78AhGdUjodG9Jlb1P@6wYT9Mymh@TsS21/Xro0YScon2FBI/DCYt1Zgz9kceLJmMllr9dTiLctO1n6GU87YI6eSy41V1zDrQZ3/xt3l7x8FEuTxznCLrXvnEKuQTOxLlkz4lk803UMINCFQYgpsEJeckVLCWcltcisv8Aw)

Comment: [103 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY6xCsIwGIT3PkXolCDmASwKOhQcXBREEIffNgmpyZ/S/qmU0mev6eJ2dxz3XQMDbJv6s1gk1WmoFCun7B2CU4BM83uwNRtEkfUEZCs2rN6DRX6jzqJ5vhiIKSuZ3i/D9sCbtCcdoJEeEIzyCkle/rKEikI3SqPoGpGsV5fHKZG4WKMztpGOnYlrtedik@dCVgEp8Xqe75r62@ZiKbLb2JPyMkSSbXpBDrmWmmN0TqSv87z8AA)

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart I feel dumb for missing the `toString` enhancement here. Good catch!

Comment: [100 bytes](https://tio.run/##PZBBS8QwEIXv/RWhp4TtBrzu2gVFFjzsxQURRGTaxphuOgnJpFJk/7o1XVZvj5k3w/deDyOsnVfYd6e5tRAjO4BB9l0wFgnItKzPFpnIWPmRsCXjUO6v4vbZma46UjCoX992DFg9j@sdv5xYQC0HQNBqUEjy8C/30JILk9SKnhKSGdTh5V4BcrGMHtEnugs6LdbIxaoshYzeGuLlpu@@fCnmbeFTYzPclXHMHGzI4PwPBoKOYklxnCKpQbpE0ucVWeTlg2qS1ipsWMlWjIME7@3EMVkrpFWo6ZPt2I0Q2@JcnOcf55e0cV7nAPmDaS4cNQXA6F2guqP36NqToiqqMKpQT1VMMdfa1fgL) - returns array of length 1 when no debugger is active, array of length at least 2 if there can be one.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 17 bytes

```js
debugger
alert(1)
```

[`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) stops execution if the debugger console is open, else it does nothing

Answer (score 3):

## [Robotalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboWar), 22 bytes

```
debug l: chronon l ifg
```

If the debugger is active, the `debug` instruction pauses execution until the end of the current game tick.  In this case, the variable "chronon" is always 1 or greater when read, and the program executes an infinite loop.  If the debugger isn't active, `debug` is a one-cycle no-op.  "Chronon" is now 0 when read, the "ifg" branch isn't taken, and execution reaches the end of the code, which is an error condition.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, 6 bytes

`dbquit`

When stopped in the debugger, this will quit debugging mode.

When not under debug, it will print an error message that it cannot be used when not stopped in the debugger.

It should be noted this only works for evaluation in the command window (one of the three ways of running MATLAB code). It won't work in a function or script as once you try to run the script or function, you stop being in debug mode during execution.

The closest you can get to something that will run in a function/script as well would be:

## MATLAB, 22 bytes

```
feature('IsDebugMode')
```

This is an undocumented command in MATLAB. If you are stopped in the debugger in a script or function, and then call another function (or command evaluation) that contains the above line, it will return true.

Outside the debugger it will return false.

If you were however to just run a script/function containing the above, even if you add a breakpoint at the start of the script/function and step through, it will return false, because again, once you start executing you stop being in the debugger temporarily.